# Cold Brew Coffee at home?

Tags: cold-brew

How to create a cold brew coffee filter at home, I've seen so many "brewers" but all were not affordable by me nor deliverable in my location please help me?

This question is not a duplicate of Choosing filter for making cold brew am asking on how to build a cold brew itself?

Comment: Are you asking for how to build a cold brew __filter__ ?

Comment: yes @OmarMiranda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to go is doing a full-immersion cold-brew.

1. Grab a Mason Jar, Jar, beer bottle, anything.
2. Grind your coffee (normally for french press)
3. Put natural temperature (24°C) pure water.
4. Let it steep at your kitchen or refrigerator (don't move it) for 12-24hrs
5. Filter the grounds (metal, paper, sock filter, whatever)

After you done that, start to modify the variables.
For me, works perfectly at natural temperature, 12hrs, v60 grind setting, Chemex filter and a 1:5.5 ratio :)

That gives a concentrate, that I diluted with ice/water until I reach typical 1:15 ratio.

**You don't need any fancy equipment. You can even do it in a glass and then *filter* with a spoon. Like a cold cupping session**

Answer (score 4):

One method is to use submerge your grounded beans in water for 24 hours and use a traditional cone filter.  Place the filter in a pour over cylinder if you have one and that will remove the grounds while leaving you the sweet, sweet cold brew nectar.  If you don't have  cylinder, you can definitely use a filter in your desired cup, just be careful with how you place it.

Answer (score 4):

If you happen to own a French press, just put your ground coffee in there with water and either leave on the counter or place in the fridge. Next day, stir if you like, press and pour. No fancy equipment, no new equipment.

Warning - it may not live up to the hype. I consider it fine, but not life-changing or "I'll never make hot coffee again."

Update: also works well if you have a drip coffee maker with filter, or a pourover - just put coffee and water in a bottle/jar in the fridge, shake occasionally, and pour through the filter part when you want it. No need to turn the machine on.